# How do I delete old[er] files from my centos /tmp directory EXCEPT certain files still in use?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I need to figure out how to automatically remove most files from my /tmp directory on a centos server. The directory keeps filling up with junk that needs to go, however there are files in there that need to stay, so:

How can I delete files in /tmp that are over 24 or so hours old AND keep files with certain name patterns?

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to the Linux & Unix Stackexchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to accomplish this.

```
find -mtime 1 -regex [your_pattern_here] -exec rm -f {} \;
```

`mtime` looks for any files older than N days old, and the `[your_pattern_here]` in this case would be the pattern of files you want to **keep**.  It'd be best to do this without the `exec` portion at the end first to make sure it's finding the files you're expecting (or more importantly, **not** finding files you want to keep)

Comment: Hi Daniel; thanks - this appears to be the correct way to go about it, even though I can use tmpwatch now. thanks.

Comment: `-mtime N` looks for files that are *exactly* N days old. For "more than 24 hours old" use `-mtime +0`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Centos has [`tmpwatch`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch).

Comment: Hi Dennis; thanks, I was not aware of tmpwatch, it does not have the ability [from the man pages] to ignore specific files but I figured out how to move the files that I needed to preserve to a more appropriate place.  looks like I'll just fire this into crontab.

Comment: @Sean: `tmpwatch` has `--exclude`. I believe its argument can be a file rather than a directory and you may be able to specify it more than once or use globbing. Sorry, I don't know for sure.